# Documentation for result object from "queue_declare" in Pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

In the following tutorial: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html, there is the following code.

```
   result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
   queue_name = result.method.queue
```

Where is this "result" object documented for Pika? I'd like to know everything I could access from this.

Comment: in java its this, http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.0.0/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.0.0/ its probably something similar in python but not familiar

Answer (score 2):

I forgot about the obvious last night. Python is often self-documenting, especially with the "dir" function. Running this inside of python, and then running "`result.__class__`"  on the result object shows that this is a METHOD object in Pika.

```
>>> r
<METHOD(['frame_type=1', 'channel_number=1', 'method=<Exchange.DeclareOk>'])>
>>> r.__class__
<class 'pika.frame.Method'>
>>> dir(r)
['INDEX', 'NAME', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_marshal', 'channel_number', 'frame_type', 'marshal', 'method']
```

Some googling brings me to these docs: https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frame.html#method

Unfortunately...

```
This class level documentation is not intended for use by those using Pika in their applications. This documentation is for those who are extending Pika or otherwise working on the driver itself.
```

So it seems that this specific example from the RabbitMQ website uses an undocumented feature from Pika. I've ended up just generating my own unique names in my application as a result.